# Global registration of field formats in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket, date-format

I've carefully studied [Jonik's entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648152/can-you-make-a-textfieldbigdecimal-accept-both-and-as-decimal-separator) about customizing BigDecimal formatting in Wicket. Thanks for this excellent piece of code. Unfortunately I can't get it to work for my use case.

I want to register date formatting globally and am using the following code in the Application subclass:

```
@Override
protected IConverterLocator newConverterLocator() {
    ConverterLocator converterLocator = new ConverterLocator();
    converterLocator.set(Date.class, new DateConverter() {

        @Override
        public DateFormat getDateFormat(Locale ignore) {
            return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        }

    });
    return converterLocator;
}
```

Then when using date fields in the web pages the code is as follows:

```
form.add(new TextField<Date>("dateField"));
```

When rendered, the date fields are showing the standard `java.text.DateFormat.SHORT` (02.11.11 11:59) formatting coming from the `org.apache.wicket.util.convert.converter.DateConverter` class instead of my custom SimpleDateFormat (02.11.2011 11:59:42).

I've checked that java.util.Date is being used throughout. Wicket version is 1.4.12.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is working fine in a 1.4.12 quickstart, using new TextField<Date>("dateField", new Model(new Date())). What's the TextField's Model? If the Form has a CompoundPropertyModel, which class is the property dateField resolves to?

Comment: Thanks Xavi. The form is a `CompoundPropertyModel` referring to a persistence entity whose `dateField` is java.util.Date. As we are using persistence entities, the fields at the end of the getter/setter chainings are raw Java data types, not implementations of IModel. Is this the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that your `newConverterLocator()` is being used? Have you debugged through `Component.getConverter(Class)` to see what's going on? You can do this easily putting a breakpoint in an override in this particular component.

Comment: I had checked this with log4j. `newConverterLocator` is being called at application start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your `dateField` has type `java.util.Date`, but actual object (loaded from database?) is e.g. `java.sql.Timestamp` or some other child of `java.util.Date`. That's why `ConverterLocator` chooses other converter instead of yours. The source code of the `ConverterLocator` has the following:

```
set(Date.class, new DateConverter());
set(Calendar.class, new CalendarConverter());
set(java.sql.Date.class, new SqlDateConverter());
set(java.sql.Time.class, new SqlTimeConverter());
set(java.sql.Timestamp.class, new SqlTimestampConverter());
```

So, you need to know the exact run-time type of your `dateField` and override converter for it.

Comment: Also, avoid using `java.util.Date` in your code. Use more specific types - `java.sql.Date` for a date (e.g. a date of birth), java.sql.Time for a time (e.g. a train arrival time) and java.sql.Timestamp for exact moment of time (e.g. a scheduled meeting time).

Comment: +1 for using the source, also this is very likely to be reason why it's still using `DateFormat.SHORT`, they all seem to default to it.

Comment: @XaviLópez I'm telling you that he has overridden converter for `java.util.Date` only, but his actual type something different, most probably `java.sql.Timestamp`, so wicket uses the default one instead.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I was referring to by saying that this is extremely likely to be the reason why Wicket was still using a converter that used `DateFormat.SHORT`.

Comment: Bingo! you are both right. `dateField` has turned out to be `java.sql.Timestamp`. So much for my understanding of how the OR layer works! Thanks both of you, I know where to go from here.

Comment: For anyone not seeing what is going on here: a `java.sql.Timestamp` is read from the database by the OR layer, but the field it is stored in is declared `java.util.Date`, which is the superclass of Timestamp. I had assumed the OR layer was converting the field types, but kan is correct that my `java.util.Date` field is just a polymorphic placeholder. Wicket's converters however query the actual class type and are not interested by any facade in between, so the "wrong" converter (from my point of view) was being called.

Comment: So... Never use _polymorphic placeholders_ if possible! I also had a lot of problems because of it. BTW, accept the answer.